# Is there a 'sociable' type plugin for ASP.NET (preferably MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Wordpress has its popular '[Sociable](http://yoast.com/wordpress/sociable/)' plugin which lets you choose from all the popular sites such as digg, stumbleupon, del.icio.us etc. and then gives you a little list of thumbnails.

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent 'plug-in' for ASP.NET - preferably something that can easily be made into an MVC Html helper extension method.

I preferably want something that I can just update when new things come along - and don't want to have to read the documentation for all these different sites to know what parameters to send.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such plugin or extension for asp.net mvc. But I'm sure you easily can create it :). And you don't need to "read the documentation for all these different sites to know what parameters to send" just look at the source code of a wordpress plugin and you'll find all necessary information there for supported sites.

Comment: thanks. was hoping someone has written one. well they probably have. i'll come back and write my own in a week or two if noone else wants to volunteer theirs :)